# GoRouter passing wrong arguments to the route when I press on `Select Widget` in flutter inspector

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, flutter-go-router

I have this route with two nested routes:

```
          GoRoute(
            parentNavigatorKey: _homePageShellNavigatorKey,
            name: MenuScreen.routeName,
            path: '/menu_screen',
            pageBuilder: (_, state) {
              assert(
                state.extra is MenuScreenArgs || state.extra == null,
                'extra of menu_screen route should be null or have a type of MenuScreenArgs,'
                ' but instead got ${state.extra.runtimeType}',
              );
              return MaterialPage(
                child: MenuScreen(
                  args: state.extra as MenuScreenArgs?,
                ),
              );
            },
            routes: [
              GoRoute(
                parentNavigatorKey: _rootNavigatorKey,
                name: CoffeeDetailsScreen.routeName,
                path: 'coffee_details_screen',
                pageBuilder: (_, state) {
                  assert(
                    state.extra != null &&
                        state.extra is CoffeeDetailsScreenArgs,
                    'extra of coffee_details_screen route should have a type of'
                    ' CoffeeDetailsScreenArgs,'
                    ' but instead got ${state.extra.runtimeType}',
                  );
                  return MaterialPage(
                    child: CoffeeDetailsScreen(
                      args: state.extra as CoffeeDetailsScreenArgs,
                    ),
                  );
                },
              ),
              GoRoute(
               // ... another nested route
              ),
            ],
          ),
```

- If I am in, say home screen, and go to `menu_screen`, then the page builder of `menu_screen`'s route is called and the assertion passes with no errors
- If I am in `menu_screen` and call this code, then the `coffee_details_screen` is successfully pushed, but the `pageBuilder` of both `menu_screen` and `coffee_details_screen` are invoked:

```
                CoffeeDetailsScreen.routeName,
                extra: CoffeeDetailsScreenArgs(productId: product.id),
              );
```

- If I am now in the `coffee_details_screen`, and I open flutter devtools and press on select widget, and I also put breakpoints on the 'pageBuilder's of `menu_screen` and `coffee_details_screen`, then I notice that they are both called, but when `menu_screen` builder is called, it is passed wrong args, it is passed the args of `coffee_details_screen` which make the assert fail:

```
  assert(
                state.extra is MenuScreenArgs || state.extra == null,
                'extra of menu_screen route should be null or have a type of MenuScreenArgs,'
                ' but instead got ${state.extra.runtimeType}',
              );
```

Why is this happening, is it a bug or something wrong in my usage of the router?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turned out to be a bug in the library itself. So it will be resolved once the maintainer fixes it in the package.
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/125900

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar problem when I press `select widget` in a route with `extra` parameters.

as this issue says providing [extra codec](https://github.com/flutter/packages/blob/main/packages/go_router/example/lib/extra_codec.dart) not solved the issue

```
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/99099
```

and I Solve it with below changes

#### before

```
SecondScreenRoute($extra: extra).replace(context);
```

#### after

```
SecondScreenRoute($extra: extra).push(context);
```